# Initializing and using a field in an abstract generic class in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, abstract

I have something like this in scala:

```
abstract class Point[Type](n: String){
    val name = n
    var value: Type = _
}
```

So far so good. The problem comes in a class that extends Point.

```
case class Input[Type](n:String) extends Point(n){
    def setValue(va: Type) = value = va
}
```

On the `setValue` line I have this problem:

```
[error]  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : va.type (with underlying type Type)
[error]  required: Nothing
[error]   def setValue(va: Type) = value = va
```

I have tried to initialize with `null` and `null.asInstanceOf[Type]` but the result is the same.

How can I initialize value so it can be used in setValue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify that `Input` implements `Point` with the generic type `Type` because for now, as it is not specified, it is considered as `Nothing` (I guess the compiler can't infer it from the `setValue` method). So you have to do the following:

```
case class Input[Type](n:String) extends Point[Type](n){
  def setValue(va: Type) = value = va
}
```

**More information**

I answered this question for the compilation error (it does compile on scala 2.9.0.1). Moreover I saw this case class as the implementation for an existing type, like 'Int'. The usage of _ is of course a bad idea in the abstract class, however it is not prohibited, but the _ is not always a null, it is the default value, for exemple: `var x:Int = _` will assign the value `0` to `x`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Merely adding the type to the case class will not compile when he attempts to use `setValue` with any other type besides `Nothing`:  

`abstract class Point[T](n:String){
  var value: T = _
  val name = n
}

case class Input[T](n:String) extends Point[T](n){
  def setValue(va:T) = value = va
}

object testTypedCaseClass{
  def test(){
    val foo = Input("foo")
    foo.setValue("bar")
    println(foo)
  }
}`

results in:
`type mismatch;`

When compiled

This is because he is declaring value to be `Nothing` by using `_` in `Point[T]`.

Comment: Can't belive I made that simple mistake. In fact that was part of the mistake, but if I change to that and keep the rest it gives me the same error.

Comment: As @JackViers mentioned, using the default value, plus some generic types which will implement the default value plus a setter which is not on the same layer as the value is quite a mess, however I don't have all your code so I suggested a simple "patch". Don't hesitate to put more details in your question.

Comment: Agree with you. I was changing some Java code to Scala and meanwhile I created new abstractions and forgot to move some things. Thanks for noticing that. However, even moving the set to the Point I keep getting the error: `value value_= is not a member test.package.Point[Type]`.

Comment: @JackViers wrong. Just because the type parameter defaults to `Nothing` doesn't mean it has to be `Nothing`. e.g. `val foo = Input[Int]("foo"); foo.setValue(3); println(foo.value)` works just fine. Alternatively, you could use `case class Input(n:String) extends Point[Int](n){ ... }`, replacing `Int` with whichever particular "value" type you want `Input` to have. You just have to specify, at least by object creation time, which type its `value` is going to have.

Comment: @DanBurton You are correct, in `val foo = Input[Int]("foo")` it works, because [T] isn't inferred, it is explicitly defined by the programmer.  However, using my example from above, `val foo = Input("foo", "bar")` uses type inference and removes a setter value which is generated for you by the compiler, and avoids the trap wherein someone may forget to type `Input[SomeType]`. Additionally, it gels with other generically typed constructs such as `List(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

package inputabstraction

```
abstract class Point[T](n:String){
  def value: T
  val name = n
}

case class Input[T](n:String, value:T) extends Point[T](n)

object testTypedCaseClass{
  def test(){
    val foo = Input("foo", "bar")
    println(foo)
  }
}
```

A simple Application to check that it works:

```
import inputabstraction._


object TestApp extends Application{
  testTypedCaseClass.test()  
}
```

**Explanation**

The first mistake you are making is `case class Input[Type](n:String) extends Point(n){`.  Point is a typed class, and so when you are calling the superclass constructor with `extends Point(n)` you need to specify the type of `Point`. This is done like this:  `extends Point[T](n)`, where T is the Type you are planning to use.

The second error is that you are both defining and declaring value:T here: `var value: Type = _`. In this statement, `_` is a value. Its value is `Nothing`. The scala compiler infers from this that `Point[T]` is `Point[Nothing]`. Thus when you attempt to set it to a type in the body of your `setValue` method, you must set it to `Nothing`, which is probably not what you want. If you attempt to set it to anything besides `Nothing`, you will get the type mismatch from above, because value is typed as `Nothing` due to your use of `_`.

The third mistake is using `var` instead of `val` or `def`.  `val` and `def` can be overridden interchangeably, which means that subtypes can override with either `val` or `def`, and the scala compiler will figure it out for you. It is best practice to define vals as functions using `def` in abstract classes and traits, because the initialization order of  subtype constructors is a very difficult thing to get right (there is an [algorithm](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.com/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html#rules) for how the compiler decides how to construct a class from its supertypes). TL#DR === use def in supertypes. Case class parameters are automatically generate `val` fields, which, since you are extending a Point, will create a val value field that overrides the def value field in `Point[T]`.

You can get away with all this `Type`||`T` abstraction in Scala because of type inference and the fact that `Point` is abstract, therefore making value extendable via val.

The preferred way of doing dependency injection like this is the [cake pattern](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/), but this example I have provided works for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, if I define value as `def value: Type` it gives me the error: `value value_= is not a member of test.package.Input[Type]`

Comment: T = Type. I believe that type abstractions must be all caps. When they are mixed case, it indicates that you are using a specific type: [S] is OK. [String] is not.

Comment: Hum... I don't think that Scala is case sensitive.

Comment: Changed to T just to test. Is the same thing :). However, if I use `var value: Type = _` it works...

Comment: Are you sure you typed Point[T]  and def value:T... "Detected sbt version 0.11.2
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
[info] Loading project definition from )
> compile
compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 23, 2012 4:36:26 PM
> run
run
[info] Running TestApp 
Input(foo,bar)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 23, 2012 4:36:28 PM
>"

Comment: I see what I had wrong above. Sorry. `val foo = Input("foo", "bar")`, not `val foo:Input = Input("foo", "bar")`. Going back to edit.